# Is the free energy of the 3 and 4 state Potts model in a positive magnetic field analytic?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, ising-model

For the Ising model in a magnetic field $h>0$  the Lee Yang theorem ensures that the free energy is analytic.

The $1 \leq  q \leq 4$ Potts model the phase transition is continous. Is it known whether the free energy of the 3 and 4 state Potts model in a positive magnetic field is analytic?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this is not know, but expected.

In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.07033 we prove that for sufficiently large strength of the magnetic field $h>0$ the free energy is analytic.